# NPM Install error with Phoenix Framework

Tags: npm, elixir, phoenix-framework

I am on debian jessie and I am trying to set up phoenix framework.  I created a new phoenix application with mix phoenix.new and then I enter that folder.  When I run 'npm install' I get these errors:

```
sudo npm install
npm ERR! git clone git@github.com:file:deps/phoenix_html Cloning into bare repository '/root/.npm/_git-remotes/git-github-com-file-deps-phoenix-html-50a27b71'...
npm ERR! git clone git@github.com:file:deps/phoenix_html Permission denied (publickey).
npm ERR! git clone git@github.com:file:deps/phoenix_html fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
npm ERR! git clone git@github.com:file:deps/phoenix_html 
npm ERR! git clone git@github.com:file:deps/phoenix_html Please make sure you have the correct access rights
npm ERR! git clone git@github.com:file:deps/phoenix_html and the repository exists.
npm ERR! 404 Not Found
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404 'phoenix_html' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, or http url, or git url.

npm ERR! System Linux 3.16.0-4-amd64
npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! cwd /home/andy/Phoenix/test_phoenix
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.29
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.21
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! git clone git@github.com:file:deps/phoenix Cloning into bare repository '/root/.npm/_git-remotes/git-github-com-file-deps-phoenix-c83d6c1a'...
npm ERR! git clone git@github.com:file:deps/phoenix Permission denied (publickey).
npm ERR! git clone git@github.com:file:deps/phoenix fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
npm ERR! git clone git@github.com:file:deps/phoenix 
npm ERR! git clone git@github.com:file:deps/phoenix Please make sure you have the correct access rights
npm ERR! git clone git@github.com:file:deps/phoenix and the repository exists.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/andy/Phoenix/test_phoenix/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

What is the issue ?

Comment: The package `phoenix_html` just [doesn't exist](https://www.npmjs.com/package/phoenix_html) on npm

Comment: @peteb is right but I'd also like to add that you can add local dependencies on npm packages too which seems to be what's happening here. `file:deps` indicates that there's some local dependencies that you're not pulling for phoenix framework.

Comment: Which means you probably need to do `mix deps.get`, as phoenix_html is an elixir dependency of phoenix.

Comment: I have the exact same problem with ubuntu 14.04lts. The npm install from the phoenix.new seems to work since there are no error messages. mix deps.get resolves fine and all dependencies are installed. Still npm install fails when manually run.

Comment: I finally fixed it with update node and npm to latest version via brew.

Answer (score 4):

One of the ways to install the latest version with nvm. For me it was very helpful. At first remove old version.

```
sudo apt-get remove nodejs
```

And install the latest one

```
wget -qO- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.31.0/install.sh | bash
nvm install 5.0
nvm use 5.0
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error then realized I was using an older version of node. Solution is to update node to newer than `v5.0.0`.